# Frequency plotting in python

Tags: python, graph, plot, frequency

I need some guidance as to go about simple plotting. There's many libraries, but I can't find this particular graph.
I have two arrays, one that holds values and the other holds the frequencies of these values.

For example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10,40,30,10,3]
```

I want to make a graph of my values- x, vs their frequency- y. Preferably, the graph columns would be filled in and not be individual dots.

The equivalent of this in R would be assigning a vector A 10 elements of 1, 40 elements of 2,  30 elements of 3, 10 elements of 4, and 3 elements of 5 and using plot(table(A))

Comment: Learn here http://matplotlib.org/examples/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use matplotlib's [bar](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [10,40,30,10,3]

plt.bar(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Values vs. Frequencies